# Es6: can't create objects from class

Tags: javascript, class, frontend

I'm trying to create objects from class "Storage" where i can store in a map multiple key-values  (using ES6), but its not working.

Its not even throwing errors, what am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
class Storage
{
    constructor( pKey, pValue )
    {
        this.key = pKey;
        this.value = pValue;
        this.map = new Map( [ pKey, pValue ] );
        console.log( this.map );//current output: (nothing)
    }


    set( pKey, pValue )
    {
        this.map.set( pKey, pValue );
    }

    get( pKey )
    {
        var result = this.map.get( pKey );
        return result;
    }

}

var myStorage = new Storage( "0", "test" );

console.log( myStorage.get( "0" ) );//espected output: "test" | current output: (nothing)
```

Comment: The error in Firefox is _“`TypeError`: iterable for `Map` should have array-like objects”_.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error thrown is

> Uncaught TypeError: Iterator value 0 is not an entry object

at the line

```
this.map = new Map([pKey, pValue]);
```

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the `Map` constructor, you need to pass it:

> An Array or other iterable object whose elements are key-value pairs (arrays with two elements, e.g. [[ 1, 'one' ],[ 2, 'two' ]]).

So, instead of passing an array with two values, pass an array which contains *another* array which contains two values:

```
this.map = new Map([[pKey, pValue]]);
```

```js
class Storage {
  constructor(pKey, pValue) {
    this.key = pKey;
    this.value = pValue;
    this.map = new Map([[pKey, pValue]]);
  }


  set(pKey, pValue) {
    this.map.set(pKey, pValue);
  }

  get(pKey) {
    var result = this.map.get(pKey);
    return result;
  }

}

var myStorage = new Storage("0", "test");

console.log(myStorage.get("0"));
```